# Get nextvalue of sequence in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, nhibernate

I would like to get nextvalue of sequence in postgresql in my controller.

I wrote a Custom Query, but I need to set it as Id (which is integer type).

How can I do that or I should write custom insert query too?

```
int count = session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT nextval('transport_id_seq')");
```

Comment: or `select max(transport_id) + 1 as nxtVal from your table`

Comment: @dude: `select max(..)` won't work in a multi-user environment. Using `max()` to generate ids either does not work or won't scale for more than a single transaction. Using a sequence is the only way to generate unique ids

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes I agree

Comment: Ya.. Thats why I'm trying to select nextval and do transaction in one Function. Because I need multi-user environment.

Comment: Your select looks fine. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: It's type mismatch. my query is NHIBernate.ISQLQuery type and count is int type..

Comment: @JustinaSeliokaite You have to *execute* the query. You can't just assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Craig Ringer says, just execute the query:

```
var count = session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT nextval('transport_id_seq')")
    .UniqueResult<long>();
```

Comment: And how can I get Integer value, not long?